# Realizar operaciones en campos de texto con formato numérico

Tags: java

Al utilizar un separador de miles dentro de un textfield no tengo problemas, lo que me está volviendo loco es cuando trato de realizar alguna operación entre las cajas de texto, porque por más que tenga configurada mi caja de texto donde va el resultado con el formateador me arroja el resultado hasta el punto nada más.
Por ejemplo si sumo `120.000 + 100.000`, en el textfield del resultado me arroja `120`

Mi código para el `DecimalFormat` que utilizo en cada caja es:

```
DecimalFormat df = new DecimalFormat("#,###");

        if (txt_suma_gnc2.getText().length() >= 1) {

            txt_suma_gnc2.setText(df.format(Integer.valueOf(txt_suma_gnc2.getText().replace(".", ""))));

        }
```

Comment: No se entiende la pregunta ni el error que estas obteniendo, por favor explica más detalladamente para que podamos ayudarte

Comment: mi teoria es que tu configuracion de localizacion esta para un sistema monetario en el que el punto es el separador de decimales, te recomiendo cambiar la configuracion de ese Locale a alguno que conozcas que no tenga esa limitacion

Comment: No tengo problemas al escribir un número, ya que me lo separa correctamente con el separador de miles, el problema viene cuando necesito hacer una operación matemática con dichos números, ya que el resultado que me arroja es hasta el punto y el resto no.

Comment: Voy a dejar parte de mi código como ejemplo para que se entienda mejor el problema, yo tengo dos textfields a los cuales les asigno un evento y configuro el separador de miles dentro de esos eventos:

Comment: private void txt_suma_gnc2KeyReleased(java.awt.event.KeyEvent evt) {                                          

        DecimalFormat df = new DecimalFormat("#,###");

        if (txt_suma_gnc2.getText().length() >= 1) {

            txt_suma_gnc2.setText(df.format(Integer.valueOf(txt_suma_gnc2.getText().replace(".", ""))));

        }

Comment: Hasta aquí no hay ningún problema, ya que si ingreso un número dentro del textfield me lo separa correctamente. El problema viene cuando realizo la sumatoria de todos los textfields para obtener un total, cree un método para realizar dicha sumatoria:

Comment: public void SumaAccesorios() {
try {
 
 int suma_gnc = Integer.parseInt(txt_suma_gnc2.getText());
 int suma_llantas = Integer.parseInt(txt_suma_llantas2.getText());
 int subtotal = suma_casco + suma_accesorios + suma_gnc + suma_llantas + suma_caja + suma_camara;
txt_subtotal.setText(String.valueOf(subtotal));
} catch (NumberFormatException e) { }
}